# How can i upload GIF images on IOS from camera roll?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I have issue with getting gif-image on IOS by picking gif from camera-roll. As result I get only thumbnail.

I try to use `react-native-fs` and method `copyAssetsFileIOS`:

```
handleSelect = (item) => () => {
        const filePath = `${APP_DIRECTORY_PATH}/${item.id}.${item.extension}`;

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && item.extension === 'gif') {
            return RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(item.uri, filePath, 0, 0)
                .then((response) => {
                    item.uri = filePath;
                    return this.props.goAddPhotos(item)
                })
                .catch((e) => console.log(e))
        }


        return this.props.goAddPhotos(item);
    };
```

// APP_DIRECTORY_PATH - `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/app`